# Strange errors with Angular Reactive Forms Validation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I'm testing a simple login functionality on my products-page component form using Angular 7 and I'm having this strange behaviour. I am trying to display the appropriate validation messages if an error exists, like if it is not a valid email, the " **must be a valid email** " message should display, and if the field is left blank, the " **email is required** ", error should display, and when you start typing, the **required message disappears** and only the valid email error message shows. This is my code.

**Addproduct.component.html**

So now I'm trying to render the span-messages if the error exists but it's not working.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="login-container" (ngSubmit)="login()">            
    <p>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email here" formControlName="email">
        <span *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">email is required</span>
        <span *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">must be a valid email</span>
    </p>            
    <p>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password here" formControlName="password">
        <span *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</span>
    </p>
    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Submit</button></p>        
</form>
```

**Addproduct.component.ts**

and this is the controller, I tried using the short notation for the validation rules but yet to no avail.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addproduct',
  templateUrl: './addproduct.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addproduct.component.css']
})
export class AddproductComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm:FormGroup;
  isSubmitted:boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private fb:FormBuilder
  ){}

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({           
      email : ['',  [Validators.required,Validators.email]],    
      password : ['', [Validators.required,Validators.min(6)]]
    });
  }

  get f(){
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }

}
```

I also changed the validation scripts to this but still to no avail

```
ngOnInit() { 
   this.loginForm = this.fb.group({           
      email : new FormControl('',  [Validators.required,Validators.email]),    
      password : new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.min(6)])
   });
}
```

and I am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking for the presence of an error where no error might exist.

You want something like this:

```
f.email.errors?.required
```

Or even:

```
f.email?.errors?.required
```

Do the same for the password field and anywhere else where the property might not exist when it is first called.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
<span *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('required', ['password'])">Password is required</span>
```

In my opinion it is a lot more easier.

Comment: good to know, i think i'd go with the former, but thanks for your opinion, duly noted.

Comment: @Andaeiii I'm glad I could help.

Comment: hey @Andaeiii if you decided to use my answer please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks :)